# Best practice for managing state of Array in React whilst providing back to back search functionality with filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question involves a number of components so I have tried to simplify.

I am trying to provide a a re-searchable menu in React. What I mean buy this is a user can search multiple times back to back. The issue is that I am using a single stateful array to search and present the results to the user. On the second search the stateful object has already been filtered and therefore the results are limited. I am tempted to have two copies of the array but is this best practice?

Further detail provided below:

The array is presented for user selection via a menu which drives the presentation of the remainder of the page.

The page component below has been simplified to contain on the elements relating to my question. It holds the GetData function which calls a post request to a server to retrieve the data destined for both the menu and the search.

The menu component shows the data and on selection sets the PreGameKey to the selected object id. This is then used to drive further functionality not included in the extract.

```
const PageComponent =()=>{
   const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
   const token = authCtx.token
   const [preGameDataGroup, setPreGameDataGroup] = useState(null)
   const [PreGameKey, setPreGameKey] = useState(null)
   const [PreGameData, setPreGameData] = useState(null)

   const GetData =()=>{
       GetOppTrades(token,setPreGameDataGroup,setPreGameKey)
     } 
   

   useEffect(GetData,[])

   useEffect(()=>{

      setPreGameData(preGameDataGroup.filter(obj => {return obj.id === PreGameKey})[0]);                

   },[PreGameKey]);

   return(
       <Search className="Search" preGameData={preGameDataGroup===null?noData:preGameDataGroup} setPreGameData={setPreGameDataGroup}></Search>

       <PreGameMenu data={preGameDataGroup===null?noData:preGameDataGroup} function={setPreGameKey}></PreGameMenu>

   );
 }       

 export default PageComponent
```

The search below takes the data and the setdata functions. At the moment as the user enters into the search box the datagroup is filtered and set. This is the same datagroup as passed to the menu component and as a result the menu filters great. The problem is that this is permanent and if a user wants to perform multiple searches in a row the data has been filtered from the previous search. What is best practice here? Do I somehow call getData to reset the datagroup on a new search (no idea how to do this without over calling) or should I make a copy of the data when the original request is made? So I have a copy to filter and show in the menu but the filtering is always done on a unfiltered copy? Or, is there some other clever way to handle this issue without duplicating the data?

```
 const Search =({preGameData, setPreGameData})=>{

     const PreGameData = Array.from(preGameData)

     const handleFilter = (e)=>{

     const searchWord = e.target.value;

     const newFilter = PreGameData.filter((item)=>{
        return item.tradename.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
     })

     setPreGameData(newFilter)
 

     }




     return (

    <div className="Search">

        <div className="SearchInputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search PreGame" onChange={handleFilter}></input>
        </div>
        <div className="SearchIcon">
            <GoSearch></GoSearch>
        </div>
    </div>
    );



  }

  export default Search
```

Comment: Im making alot of assumptions here because of laziness, but the general thumb of rule is for any filter,search etc function dont mutate original data point, create a copy, apply the changes you want and present it.

Comment: @Breezer thank you. So it is normal to have a copy array? One which is unfiltered and acts as the base for each new filtering and another for the presentation of the filtered data to the user? If so, do you want to answer the Q and I will accept?

Comment: yes this is the normal practise anything else would be just inefficient, no need to for the points im just happy to help ty